# Excel - Pivot View Multiple Column Data without Expand/Collapse

Tags: excel, pivot-table, multiple-columns

I am trying to display multiple Columns of identical information without a Dropdown with the columns side by side and only appearing once.

My base information is as follows:

```
SKU             Title                               Shipped
123-BJ00040-14  Betsey Johnson Women's BJ00040-14   2
123-BJ00131-29  Betsey Johnson Women's BJ00131-29   2
123-BJ00198-02  Betsey Johnson Women's BJ00198-02   2
123-BJ00131-29  Betsey Johnson Women's BJ00131-29   4
123-BJ00040-14  Betsey Johnson Women's BJ00040-14   3
```

In other words I have Row data with multiple columns of the same information for example the Column SKU always correlates to the Column Title. I am trying to view both the SKU and Title as non expand/collapse columns in the pivot and only SUM the Shipped Column so my pivot table should look like:

```
SKU             Title                               Shipped
123-BJ00040-14  Betsey Johnson Women's BJ00040-14   5
123-BJ00131-29  Betsey Johnson Women's BJ00131-29   6
123-BJ00198-02  Betsey Johnson Women's BJ00198-02   2
```

Allowing me to copy the SKU, Title and Summed Shipped Qty together.

Comment: Move Shipped from being a Row field to a Value field and summarize with Sum.

Comment: Agree with @DougGlancy.  Also, if it's not obvious, you should set `SKU` and `Title` to be fields in the `Rows` section and not columns.  It may look better if you also change the report style to Tabular (or possibly Outline).  Tabular will display all the data in the same row which is probably what you want.